# Could you please provide instructions or Code on exporting point coordinates from a CATIA product to Excel using VB?

Tags: excel, coordinates, catia

I'm seeking a VB script compatible with either Excel or CATIA. This script should facilitate exporting the coordinates of points from a CATProduct to an Excel spreadsheet. Given the substantial volume of points involved, automation is crucial.

Moreover, I anticipate the need to selectively export particular points in the future.

i tried extracting the points from parnts and it didn't work if anyone the vb code can you pls share it here or give instructions